# How do I print multiple slides per page?

Tags: printing, slideshows

I have a Mathematica 10 presentation (not made by me).

The slides are *very* short and very many.

I'd like to print it, but printing 100+ pages each with 2 or 3 equations seems like a waste to me.

Is there a way to print multiple slides per page, ideally as many as can fit?

Thanks.

Comment: Is [Modify pdf file to have multiple slides per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190417/modify-pdf-file-to-have-multiple-slides-per-page) of some Help?

Comment: Not really. I'm no Mathematica expert and I don't know if this is the norm, but my "slides" do *not* look like "slides" in the traditional sense, they are a couple of equations, period. Printing each on a separate page and then fitting 4 such pages on a single one would be an unreadable botch job, possibly even worse than printing them on separate pages. I'd like my slides (which consist of a couple equations and are not of fixed aspect ratio) to be printed one after another - in other words, like I see them in Mathematica.

Comment: Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AL3uC.png